# How can I enable future years on my datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm really noob in web development and I'm using TailwindCSS and AlpineJS on my project and I need to allow users to pick future years aswell as the current year on my date picker, so the user can pick 2020, 2021, 2022,..., dates.

Here's what I made so far in the bellow code snippet:

```
`https://codepen.io/fernandorcoelho/pen/BazXwjX?editors=1010`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to remove some logic from your `next arrow`. Here is the opening for your `next arrow`.

I've added this logic to your `button`

```
 @click="if (month == 11) {month=0; year++} else {month++};
```

```
<button type="button" class="inline-flex p-1 transition duration-100 ease-in-out rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none"  @click="if (month == 11) {month=0; year++} else {month++}; getNoOfDays()">
```

Here is the [working demo](https://codepen.io/sifat009/full/OJXKOJX)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!